# Flutter: how to make a TextField with HintText but no Underline?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, underline, hint

This is what I'm trying to make:

[image]

In the Flutter docs for Text Fields (https://flutter.io/text-input/) it says you can remove the underline by passing `null` to the decoration. However, that also gets rid of the hint text.

I do not want any underline whether the text field is focused or not.

**UPDATE:** updated accepted answer to reflect changes in Flutter SDK as of April 2020.

Answer (score 491, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
TextField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
    hintText: 'Username'
  ),
),
```

or if you need other stuff like icon, set the border with `InputBorder.none`

```
InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Username',
  ),
),
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without importing the `material` package? i.e. for `Cupertino` theme?

Comment: I'd like avoid:  `InputDecoration' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BoxDecoration'` type error

Comment: 'This feature was deprecated after v1.13.2.' in docs

Comment: Can we please mark this as the real solution? It is officially used in Flutter 2.2.0

Answer (score 324):

New Flutter SDK since after integration of web and desktop support you need to specify individually like this:

```dart
TextFormField(
  cursorColor: Colors.black,
  keyboardType: inputType,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    contentPadding:
      EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
    hintText: "Hint here"),
)
```

Comment: How can I give a radius after applying this solution?

Comment: @JayTillu This video demonstrates it quite well: https://youtu.be/3zddqfn0dfc

Comment: Or u can just simly use one and only `border: InputBorder.none` to turn off all kinds of borders (i.e. `focusedBorder`, `enabledBorder`, `errorBorder`, `disabledBorder`).

Comment: using this will give you 100 % border less even for TextFormField. and you can style you component or make stateless widget component its up-to you

Comment: You can use outline border with fill true/false in input decoration.

Answer (score 58):

Here is a supplemental answer that shows some fuller code:

[image]

```
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.tealAccent,
      borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(32),
    ),
    child: TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        hintText: 'Search your trips',
        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Notes:

- The dark background (code not shown) is `Colors.teal`.
- `InputDecoration` also has a `filled` and `fillColor` property, but I couldn't get them to have a corner radius, so I used a container instead.

Answer (score 34):

I found no other answer gives a border radius, you can simply do it like this, no nested `Container`

```
  TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 22):

change the focused border to none

```
TextField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
          hintText: 'Subject'
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 12):

To remove TextField underline border in Flutter, you can simply set `border` to  `InputBorder.none`.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Hint Text',
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

`TextField(style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,fontSize: 18,decorationThickness: 0.0))`. 
It's showing without underline with `decorationThickness:0.0`.

Answer (score 5):

To make a Borderless TextFormField i found below solution:

It is without using container.

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                         borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),

           labelText: "Student email/id",
           floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    height: 4,
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 160, 26, 179)),
                                
           filled: true,
           fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
           prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                ),
           ),
```

Sample Normally:
[image: Normally Looks like this]

While having input error:
[image: On error]

While user input:
[image: while entering data]

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```dart
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
    hintText: "Search your trips",
    hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.cyan[200],
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: const Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            Container(
         height: 50,
          // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.tealAccent,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
          child: TextFormField(
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            // keyboardType: TextInputType.,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
              hintText: 'Search your trips',
              suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Default

[image]

```
 Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: const TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(), hintText: "Search Your tips"),
      ),
    ),
```

---

#### Outline Border

[image]

```
 Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
          ),
          hintText: "Search Your tips",
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

---

#### No Border

[image]

```
 Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: const TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none, hintText: "Search Your tips"),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the border for every case in TextField

**Code:**

```
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            focusedErrorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: 'Senders name',
          ),
        ),
```

**Output:**

[image: TextField without borders]

Answer (score 0):

To remove underline **`border: InputBorder.none,`**

For hint use **`hintText: 'Hint Text'`**

```
   TextFormField(
      InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: 'Hint Text',
      ),
    ),
```